# Can I use php arrays to insert into a mysql database on a different host?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select data from my localhost and then insert into another database on a different host. I'm a total noob on arrays, tried other ways before and it didn't worked. I though closing the first connection and opening the second connection later would be enough to solve my problem. But it wasnt.
I'm not getting any error messages, just a blank page, and nothing happening.

This is the code:

For this example I'm just selecting 1 user, which is the one with username 'martin',
but for the real deal I'll have to do this with 8000 users.

```
<?php
$db1 = mysql_connect('localhost', '1st HOST USER', '1st HOST PASS') or die ("No pudo conectar base datos 1");
mysql_select_db('1 host DB', $db1);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'martin' ");
$count  = mysql_num_rows($result);
$usuarios = array();
i = 0;
if ($count <= 0) {
    echo msgbox("There are no users.");
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($usuarios, $row['username']);
        i++;
    }
}
mysql_close($db1);

$db2 = mysql_connect('2nd host IP', '2nd host USER', '2nd host PASS') or die ("No pudo conectar base datos 2");
mysql_select_db('2nd host DB', $db2);
$completados = 0;
    while($i > 0){
        $usuario = $usuarios[i];
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO prueba('usuario')VALUES('$usuario') ", $db2);
        i--;
        if($insert){
            $completados++;
        }
    }
    echo 'Agregados: ' . $completados;

mysql_close($db2);

?>
```

Comment: Not with the `mysql_*` methods. You would need to build your queries on the fly by looping over the array and building a string. Using mysql**i**_* or PDO, you can prepare a query and just call execute and pass in the array.

Comment: Couldn't agree more :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate through the array `usuario` and execute that SQL statement for every username in the array, that will work. Also, (even though you may be a beginner), the current way you are executing your SQL statements is dangerous. Have a look at [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), as they can also make the array iteration and insertion faster.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with iterate throught the array usuario? (I don't speak too much english) Could you show me an example please?

Comment: @user1913644 Sure. Have a read of [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), which is a for loop, that you can use to go through every element in the array. Use one of these to insert each user individually.

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < count($usuarios); $i++) {
      $usuario = $usuarios[i];
  $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO prueba('usuario')VALUES('$usuario') ", $db2);
  if($insert){
   $completados++;
  }
 } Like this?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
$usuarios = array();
i = 0;
```

and

```
while($i > 0){
    $usuario = $usuarios[i];
```

should be

```
$usuarios = array();
$i = 0;

while($i > 0){
    $usuario = $usuarios[$i];
```

You missed the dollar sign on the $i

If this helped solve your issue please **do** consider taking a look at the problems other people have pointed out, mysql_* functions are as good as deprecated, moving over to PDO would even be better :-).

**Old post**

By just taking a quick peek I couldn't see anything wrong so fast, could you please verify if the second database host allows you to connect from the machine your calling this code from?

Comment: Yes the 2nd host allows connection from the first one.

Comment: Did you inspect the other missing $i's I left as an exercise? :-)